# Can this grille be found in any other car other than a Dodge Stratus?

Tags: part-identification, vehicle-identification

**EDIT**

- Since finding those numbers I plugged them into google and it appears the part number is for a [Dodge Stratus](https://www.google.com/search?q=04805900AB&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS682US682&oq=04805900AB&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.659j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)... Could it potentially go to another type of car as well or would the grille be a unique thing? As far as I know some vehicle models are kind of shared between companies...
- Looking at these pictures myself I realized almost the entire grill pieces are there... Looking at them again i realized that there is some numbers on the back... do these help identify anything by chance? (I will add a small pic below as well):
- DC () 04805901AB LH CHG A
- ASM 04805900AB CHG A
- MADE IN CANADA
- PC + ABS

I am hoping you all might be able to help me out. Long story short my brother-in-law's car was involved in a hit and run last night. I plan to drive around like a detective for a week or so checking out cars as I drive by them, but I had the thought that you all might be able to help me figure out what I am searching for because the car left behind some pieces of itself... By any chance does anyone recognize what car it may have been from these pieces? Thanks for any help!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I think your sleuthing and finding the part number is about as good as you're going to get as far as the type of car this came off of. I don't think you're going to go much further beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this website: https://www.factorychryslerparts.com/products/Chrysler/Sebring/GRILLE-Radiator/4284192/04805900AB.html

Your second part #:     04805900AB

Fits the following models, including the Chrysler Sebring, however, you will notice the stock sebring part depicted there is not hexagonal in its subdivisions, however, some models of sebring (at least in prior years) had a similar pattern. In other words, it may indeed fit, but I'm not sure how many of those Sebring models it will actually match the factory styling with:

- Chrysler Sebring 2.4L 4 Cyl A/T CONVERTIBLE   2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.4L 4 Cyl A/T SEDAN     2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T CONVERTIBLE  2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T CONVERTIBLE Limited  2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T CONVERTIBLE Touring  2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T GTC Convertible  2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T SEDAN    2005
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T SEDAN Limited    2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T SEDAN Touring    2005, 2006
- Chrysler Sebring 2.7L V6 A/T TSI SEDAN    2005, 2006
- Dodge Stratus 2.4L 4 Cyl A/T SE SEDAN     2005
- Dodge Stratus 2.4L 4 Cyl A/T SXT SEDAN    2005, 2006
- Dodge Stratus 2.7L V6 A/T ES SEDAN    2005
- Dodge Stratus 2.7L V6 A/T R/T SEDAN   2005, 2006
- Dodge Stratus 2.7L V6 A/T SE SEDAN    2005
- Dodge Stratus 2.7L V6 A/T SXT SEDAN   2005, 2006